# The equivalent weight of HNO3 in the following reaction

Tags: redox

The equivalent weight of HNO3 in the following reaction is ‘x’, then the value of x/21 is

3Cu+8HNO3⟶3Cu(NO3)2+2NO+4H2O

in this I atempted by using redox formulas but my answer is comming 1 but correct answer is 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term equivalent weight is used in conjuction with normality (which is quite obsolete, except in the industry). Anyway, whenever you determine equivalent weight, you have to know beforehand whether you are considering a given "molecule" as an acid or as an reducing/oxidizing agent. This is where the confusion sets in.

Nitric acid as an acid is a monoprotic acid: It's equivalent weight is the same as its formula weight

Calculating the equivalent weight of nitric acid as an oxidizing agent is another story, *it depends on how the redox equation is written*.

From your equation nitric acid is acting as an oxidizing agent because there is no nitrate ion on the right hand side and the oxidation state of N is different on both sides:

$\ce{HNO3}$ is converting to NO. In the answer above, you already have the equation

$\ce{ NO3−}$ +3e => NO

In this case, the equivalent weight of nitric acid is 1/3 (formula weight).

As you can see equivalent weight is very much dependent on the way you write the equation. This will come with practice.

Comment: I'd agree that this is a redox reaction, but the OP gives the answer as equivalent weight factor as 4, so the person who made the answer key was considering the half cell reaction as an acid-base reaction.

Comment: The student's answer of 1 is correct. 63/3 = 21, x/21 gives us 21/21 =1; whoever wrote this question made a typo in the answer.

Comment: Ah, yes. When I read the question I thought the student misstated the problem so I jumped to 4H+ vs 3e- confusion. The question itself was weird. I realize now that you are right. The answer has to be an integer, so 1 is the only possibility.

Answer (score -1):

["Equivalent weight"](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/E/E02192.html) has been [depreciated](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0003267094800154) by IUPAC because it is ambiguous in some cases. To me this is one of them. The relevant half cell reaction is:

$$\ce{NO3−(aq) + 4H+ + 3e−  <=> NO(g) + 2H2O(l)}\quad\quad E = +0.958$$

Thus there are $\ce{4H+}$ but only $\ce{3e-}$. So is the equivalent weight 1/4 or 1/3 as much as the molarity?

Comment: can you explain it more clearly

Comment: I don't see how. What is confusing about my answer to you?

Comment: but the answer is different

Comment: You mean 4 vs 3? Did you follow the link and read the definition of equivalent weight?